# Loading image not displaying on Safari 7/8/9 on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I am representing a very common issue here but with weird behavior. Hoping to get my mistake cleared out or a solution.
I am trying to show a loading image upon submission of form by clicking a button. I am using simple htmls and javascript on my jsp page. Below is the code for your reference -

```
<input type="button" onClick="submitForm('myaction','mycontext')" />

<div id="progressBar" style="display:none;">
 <img id="gifimg" src="../images/load.gif">
</div>

function submitForm(action, originalContext){
    document.getElementById('progressBar').style.display='block';
    document.forms[0].action = document.forms[0].action + "?method=" + action + "&originalContext=" + originalContext;
    document.forms[0].submit();
    return;
}
```

**ISSUE** - Above code works perfectly fine in the Universe except **Safari 7, 8, 9 on Mac 10.9, 10.10, 10.11** respectively. Would really appreciate if someone can look into it and suggest. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Are the browsers angry with the onClick attribute?

```
<input id="fibble" type="button" value="click">

<div id="progressBar" style="display:none;">
 loading
</div>


document.getElementById('fibble').addEventListener('click', submitForm);

function submitForm(action, originalContext){
    document.getElementById('progressBar').style.display='block';
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Will for the response.
addEventListener is not working though. Nor attachEvent.

Let me go back to my original question and if I remove "document.form[0].submit();", I could see loading image, however form will not get submitted. Any hint?

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. This is a classic "submit a form but don't refresh the page" problem. If you Google it, you'll see a ton of versions that use jQuery. 

But!, if you start here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData and start reading, you'll learn all about this cool object that makes it easy to send a form via AJAX.